# questions about cloning win7 pro in a domain environment

Tags: windows

I used a client as the source, unjoin domain and remove antivirus software. Then I run sysprep /generalize /oobe. Next, I ghost the whole hdd, and restore the image to the target computer. Then I renamed the computer, rejoined domain and antivirus.
Up to this moment, it seems everything is working fine. But, when I use a domain user acc to logon, and open the youtube link in powerpoint, it failed, stating the IE is not responding. Also, I failed to use smartboard orientation.
After I add this user to local admin group, everything works fine, but the source computer doesn't need to do this.
It seems that I have missed some critical steps before using sysprep. Is it needed to remove all roaming profile before unjoining domain?
Or any other steps missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the profiles from the computer before creating an image. When you Sysprep you should really have only the one Administrator account present that you are running Sysprep from.

As Jim B pointed out, you really shouldn’t be creating images from live machines, but should instead use a minimal reference image and a deployment solution like MDT to inject apps, drivers, etc. This avoids conflicts like this that can be hard to pin down considering the number of variables in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

That in theory should have worked, but I'd urge you to create an MDT image instead. You can use a clean (no app no drivers) image and add the apps during deploy.  Without more details I can't tell what happened to the sysprep image.